# apply composite pattern to general graph models

Tags: c#, graph-theory, data-modeling, self-reference

I want to build up a data model, that mainly consists of a graph to be traversed later. Special requirement: a node inside the graph could either be an action to be executed or a container with another graph of actions or containers. During traversal, it has to be checked, if the current node is a container and if so, a traversal of the subgraph shall be started.

**How could this be achieved? How should a data model look like, to build up a structure like in the picture below?**

[image]

So far I got some classes. there are several action types, thus I am using an interface here

```
public interface IAction : IContainer
{
    public ActionType ActionType{ get; set; }
    public Name { get; set; }
}
```

the container contains just a name and a self-reference. I tried to accomplish this initially by using an interface as well, but then I can later only access the interface properties, not the container properties

```
public interface IContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Container : IContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IContainer Content { get; set; }
}
```

in main the test usage looks like this:

```
myJob.Content = new QuikGraph.BidirectionalGraph<IContainer, QuikGraph.Edge<IContainer>>();
myJob.Content.AddVertex(new MyCustomAction()
{
    ActionType = ActionType.MyCustomAction,
    Name = "Test"
});

myJob.Content.Vertices.First().Name // only property I could access, no action-specific ones
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and whats the question

Comment: I updated the question and added a picture to clarify the goal. Is it now better understandable?

Comment: An useful resource about graphs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379574(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#datastructures20_5_topic3

Comment: I edited the headline of the question to make the result easier to find later for others. Does the new header make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing an operation (a method) in `IContainer` that would be callable from any node in your graph and which would behave as you expect (a container forwarding the call to all its enclosed actions and an action doing the real operation).

Also, instead of holding a single reference to an `IContainer` in `Container` you better have a collection of children `IContainer`, since in your diagram a container has 3 actions.

See the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) for more explanation.

```
public interface IContainer
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void DoWork();
}

public sealed class Action1 : IAction
{
    public override DoWork()
    {
        //Do the real work
    }
}

public sealed class Container : IContainer
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<IContainer> _children;
    public Container(IEnumerable<IContainer> children) => _children = children.ToList();
    public override DoWork()
    {
        foreach(var child in _children)
        {
            child.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try this today in the evening and give you a reply :-)

Comment: one more question, @Spotted: it seems the composite pattern is specifically designed for tree structures. Does it apply as well for graphs? See my example, a node can have more than one incoming edge

Comment: @TarekSalha Indeed it is specifically designed for tree but graphs are very close to them. The main difference is that every node can have children. In this case move the children collection in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

this is the result, that I came up with. It took me some time to know how to model this, but eventually I applied the composite pattern as suggested by @Spotted. I completely removed the quikgraph library from the classes and outsourced it to another service, that I only call, when I want to traverse the graph or check for cycles, etc...

Also, I chose to not link entities directly to each other, but instead by name, because otherwise serialization outputs me doubled information (nodes could be referenced more than once).

```
public interface IContainer
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IList<string> DependsOn { get; set; }
    void DoWork();
    void AddDependency(string name)
}

public interface IAction : IContainer
{
    // more common stuff
}

public sealed class Action1 : IAction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    IList<string> DependsOn { get; set; }
    public DoWork()
    {
        //Do the real work
    }
    
    public void AddDependency(string name)
    {
        this.DependsOn.Add(name);
    }
}

public sealed class Container : IContainer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> DependsOn { get; set; }
    public IList<IContainer> SubGraph { get; set; }

    public override DoWork()
    {
        foreach(var item in SubGraph)
        {
            item.DoWork();
        }
    }

    public void AddSubGraph(IList<IContainer> subGraph)
    {
        this.SubGraph = subGraph;
    }
}
```

thanks for your help, dude!